# How much transaction fees have Bitcoin users incurred since the beginning of Bitcoin?

Tags: transaction-fees, history

I wonder the following: how much transaction fees have Bitcoin users incurred since the beginning of Bitcoin?

Comment: In all financial systems, the total historical transaction costs will always eventually far exceed the total money supply many times over. The former tends to inifinity, the latter, in this case, can never exceed 21M.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know the answer, and I've never seen such statistics, looking forward to see a concrete answer.
The fastest way to measure could be by looking at each block: the amount of coinbase transaction is the sum of the block reward and the sum of all fees in the transactions in the block. (E.g. the current last block 766140 has a coinbase amount of 6.35782892, of which 6.25 is the block reward, thus 0.10782892 btc is the sum of fees in this block. Some explorers display the total fee per block amount. Such an analysis could be run on a local copy of the blockchain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no identity on Bitcoin it's not possible to know the total fees which have been paid by "users" of the system. For all we know a miner may have included transactions paying fees to himself.

Actively monitoring transaction which were broadcast to the P2P network and then mined could give a fairly reliable approximation. As the fee attached to a transaction can be collected by any miner, presumably such transactions are made by users.